# using file/db as the buffer for very big numpy array to yield data prevent overflow?

Tags: python, memory-management, numpy

In using the numpy.darray, I met a memory overflow problem due to the size of data，for example:

Suppose I have a 100000000 * 100000000 * 100000000 float64 array data source, when I want to read data and process it in memory with np. It will raise a Memoray Error because it works out all memory for storing such a big array in memory.

Then maybe using a disk file / database as a buffer to store the array is a solution, when I want to use data, it will get the necessary data from the file / database, otherwise, it is just a python object take few memory.

Is it possible write such a adapter?

Thanks.

Rgs,
KC

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/) or [numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), maybe they fit your needs.

best, Peter

Comment: thanks, however, they are not, I need to write a sqlite based numpy.array reader for the SQL language, the most suitable is ATpy, however, it can not "lazy read"...

Answer (score 0):

If You have matrices with lots of zeros use scipy.sparse.csc_matrix. 
It's possible to write everything, for example You can override numarray array class.

Comment: thanks, that may not what I need, what I want to do is something like linux command "cat big_file | more" then I can usin page function to seek from different pages.